# Whatsapp desktop cursor become overwrite mode

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, whatsapp

I accidentally pressed a combination of keys (I think one of them is Shift key) and my type cursor enters OVR (overwrite) mode instead of INS (insert) mode when selecting previous characters. In this OVR mode I cannot insert words/characters, but instead replace them as I type.

[image: Whatsapp desktop OVR mode]

**What is the key combination to switch it back to INS mode?**

Comment: I have the same problem in MacOSX today ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such behavior is toggled with <kbd>Insert</kbd> in many programs. I believe Whatsapp isn't different.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC I had to press the function key and the insert key to turn it off.